# Python -- Will I ever use new features?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

So I've been reading the "What's New" section of the Python 3.6.1 docs today because I recently realized how behind I'm getting in the language since my development is primarily scientific in nature and is 100% focused in Python 2.7.10+.

There are, in my opinion, an overwhelming amount of new features like the typing module and support for C style typedefs, asyncio and it's associated features like asynchronous iterators and context managers, meta-classes and their functionality, and pathlib with path-like objects in the new release. Quite frankly reading all of this makes me nervous to transition to Python 3.6+.

I initially thought transitioning to Python3 would be relatively trivial. Things like built-ins changing their return types from lists to iterators, strings becoming unicode by default, and print becoming a function are all easy to stomach. But 6 minor versions later and it seems almost like a different language.

Does anyone who works regularly in Python use these things? Are they useful and prolific enough that I should spend my time getting to know them well and/or porting old code? Are there resources out there that I'm unaware of that can help me navigate the newer waters?

Comment: Yes, there are huge advancements mainly on async programming that per se are worth updating yourself. Just because old people are used to old habits doesn't mean you must forever be stuck on Python 2.7...

Comment: Although I would argue that is a very opinion based question, I'm very interested on reading more about it :P

Comment: What Python feature do you mean by "C style typedefs"?

Comment: You don't need to use all these new features and still port your code to Python 3.

Comment: Transitioning to python 3 _is_ relatively trivial. Just because there are new features doesn't mean you have to use them. You don't have to spend time porting old code either, because _if it ain't broke, don't fix it_. It's worth transitioning to python 3 precisely because it's so trivial. You can take your time familiarizing yourself with all the new features.

Comment: Any general purpose language will suffer from this.  Unless you write a language yourself, languages will always have features that are of no use to you.  By all means learn about new features, but don't worry about them, they are optional.  Use the features you need to get your job done.

Comment: Python 3.x for me a whole new world. 99% of my python coding time I use 2.x version. I wondering will process change from 2nd to 3rd version painful.

Comment: @mkrieger1: I think the OP is referring to [type aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases).

Comment: @mkrieger1 the typing module has a NewType function which allows you to write code analogous to typedef statements in C. The example they use is `from typing import NewType
UserId = NewType('UserId', int)
some_id = UserId(524313)` which I consider similar to something like `typedef struct { int idNumber;} UserId; UserId someId = {.idNumber=524313};` (barring syntax errors here)

Comment: I see why people marked this as opinion based and put it on hold. I was hoping for good discussion rooted in other people's experience with Python 3.X. But thank you for those who have replied and may reply in the future.